# Is there anything like Microsoft Sync for the home or media center computer?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, home-server, microsoft-sync

I just returned from a business trip where my rental car (A free upgrade to a Lincoln MKZ!) had the Microsoft Sync system built into it.  You know, from the commercial:  'Play artist, Right On Dynamite' ... [machine voice] 'Playingartistrightondynamite'.

I had my doubts, but I must say, after using it for three days and having the ability to do full control of music, phone, and other sound all from my phone...it's awesome. Plus the ability to call people just by talking.  I realize that would be harder to do, since you'd need to mic the entire area you might be in, but I could live with having to be in range of a microphone connected to a PC.

You do need to have a phone with Bluetooth audio capability, which I'm fortunate to have, but I was thinking this would be just amazing at home...you could just keep your phone in a pocket or on your desk and it's like the ultimate stereo remote.

So...how would I set this up at home?  I have a couple Macs at home with bluetooth on them, and I have a couple PCs of 2-3 year old vintage that are available.  I know Bluetooth to USB dongles are cheap.  I'm not really a programmer, but I can hang drivers together.  Is it a pipe dream, or could I set this up?  Anyone got anything like this working now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that the Windows Bluetooth Stack (Broadcomm / Widcomm) does not implement the HFP Bluetooth Profile used for Hands-Free Telephone stuff (at least what I coudl gather so far).

There is not much information on that topic anywhere to be found, but I'd really love to be able to telephone with my PC headset instead of having to switch to a different headset when answering a call.

Comment: Don't I know there's nothing out there.  Even what you talk about is progress...  I just think it would be amazing to have your home stereo mute and ring for phone calls, and then you could just speak into the air.  Star Trek here we come!